# Wordpress not running on Docker port 8000

Tags: wordpress, macos, docker, docker-compose, docker-desktop

I'm trying to set up wordpress with Docker Desktop on **Mac**. I followed this guide: https://docs.docker.com/compose/wordpress/

When I run `docker-compose up -d`, it tells me db & wordpress are up-to-date. But, visiting `localhost:8000` results in this error: **This page isn’t working localhost didn’t send any data. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE** . I also tried `127.0.0.1:8000` - same result.

Again, `curl localhost:8000` just gives me: **(52) Empty reply from server**

I'm also using Local by Flywheel on my machine. Could that cause a conflict perhaps?

My **docker-compose.yml**:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     ports:
       - "8000:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
volumes:
    db_data: {}
```

Comment: Please check if the port is open with `netstat -plunt | grep 8000`, I am not a Mac user I don't know if you have `netstat` but I hope so :)

Comment: @HernanGarcia netstat is there... but `-plunt` seems isn't the right syntax for Mac. Will need to dig that up.

Comment: Join this chat
https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189566/wordpress-not-running-on-docker-port-8000

Comment: so I did `sudo lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN -n -P`. This gives me a list of all the ports being listened to. I see a line like this: `com.docke   646 username   18u  IPv4 0x266159bcd6f45489      0t0  TCP *:8000 (LISTEN)` and this: `com.docke   646 username   20u  IPv6 0x266159bce9382b09      0t0  TCP [::1]:8000 (LISTEN)`

Comment: I'm in the chat @HernanGarcia

Comment: @HernanGarcia I solved it, but I don't know why it works :)) I followed what someone had done here: https://forums.docker.com/t/wordpress-example-in-docker-compose-fails/30438/3 . Basically I changed volume to `db_data:/var/lib/mysql2`, and also changed wordpress image to `wordpress:php7.1`. After running docker-compose it worked. It's still a mystery to me.

Comment: Crazy huh? it seems a Docker+Mac issue, glad to hear that you are able to move on on your journey to docker ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, but I don't know why it worked. I followed what someone had done here: https://forums.docker.com/t/wordpress-example-in-docker-compose-fails/30438/3

Basically I changed volume to `db_data:/var/lib/mysql2`, and also changed wordpress image to `wordpress:php7.1`. After running `docker-compose up` it worked.